# How do I add frames to this class to divide everything up?

Tags: python, tkinter, frame

Im trying to divide this page up. Can anyone help me out understanding how to divide PageOne into frames.  I want to put in a navbar section just for buttons and another section for entry forms

```
class rhizoApp(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        #tk.Tk.wm_iconbitmap(self, default="rhizo.ico")
        tk.Tk.wm_title(self, "Rhizo Control Center")

        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand = True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.frames = {}

        for F in (StartPage, PageOne, PageTwo):        
            frame = F(container, self)
            self.frames[F] = frame
            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

        self.show_frame(StartPage)

    def show_frame(self, cont):
        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()

class StartPage(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        label = tk.Label(self, text="Home Page", font=LARGE_FONT, bd=2, bg='red', width=50, height=5)
        label.grid(row=0, column=0, pady=10, padx=10, sticky='N', columnspan=10)



        button1 = tk.Button(self, text="Testing", relief='raised', command=lambda: controller.show_frame(PageOne))
        button1.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky='w', padx=10, pady=10)
        button2 = tk.Button(self, text="Analysis", command=lambda: controller.show_frame(PageTwo))
        button2.grid(row=2, column=9, sticky='se', padx=10, pady=10)
```

Im just getting a little lost because I tried doing

```
frame1=tk.Frame(parent)
```

also:

```
frame1=tk.Frame(self)
```

but python just hangs.

Comment: your indentation is incorrect in your code. Can you please fix it?

Comment: done. sorry for how it got copied.